# What is the correct xpath that will provide single flow resolution in logic apps

Tags: xml, azure, xpath, azure-logic-apps

Below is my xml file, I am able to decode the xpath for the `/PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMSTRUCTURE/ITEM/@parent` attribute level. At that level you can see there are 3 items with the same parent : `items ((55166579,55063477,55025930)) and parent (55166581)`. Following xpaths have got me the items I required from the specific xml level :

```
xpath(xml(items('For_each')),'string(//@number)')
xpath(xml(items('For_each')),'string(//@version)')
xpath(xml(items('For_each')),'string(//@parent)')
xpath(xml(items('For_each')),'string(//@parentversion)')
```

Now these items have more information in the : `/PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMS//ITEM` tag where I need to process and match the item numbers and extract their respective , information. Please help do I go about it. If possible I would like to do this in a single flow of the logic app. Some how match the number attribute to the `/PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMS/ITEM/ITEMNUMBER` and extract the additional info. Experts humbly request your indulgence.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM>
    <HEADER>

    </HEADER>
    <ITEMS>
        <ITEM>
            <ITEMNUMBER>55166581</ITEMNUMBER>
            <ITEMREVISION>B</ITEMREVISION>
            <CATALOGUEID/>
            <DRAWINGNUMBER>55166581/B</DRAWINGNUMBER>
            <CUSTOMERDRAWINGNUMBER/>
            <ITEMNAME>
                <NAME lang="default">Plate</NAME>
                <NAME lang="en/US">Plate</NAME>
                <NAME lang="fi/FI">Levy</NAME>
                <NAME lang="sv/SE">Pl&#229;t</NAME>
                <NAME lang="fr/FR">PLAQUE</NAME>
                <NAME lang="de/DE">Schild</NAME>
            </ITEMNAME>
            <ECNCHANGEID>ECN-BG00009133</ECNCHANGEID>
            <UNITOFMEASURE>each</UNITOFMEASURE>
            <TECHNICALDESCRIPTION>Rear plate, right, welding assembly</TECHNICALDESCRIPTION>
            <ADDITIONALDESCRIPTION/>
            <PRODUCTTYPEDESCRIPTION/>
            <SPAREPARTDESCRIPTION/>
            <SPAREPARTINDICATOR>Not spare part</SPAREPARTINDICATOR>
            <SPAREPARTDOCUMENTAVAILABLE>false</SPAREPARTDOCUMENTAVAILABLE>
            <RECOMMENDEDSPAREPART>false</RECOMMENDEDSPAREPART>
            <SPAREPARTSERVICECATEGORY/>
            <SPAREPARTOEM/>
            <AFTERMARKETCLASS/>
            <ITEMREVISIONPUID>maMAZ1OJh7yqPA</ITEMREVISIONPUID>

        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <ITEMNUMBER>55166579</ITEMNUMBER>
            <ITEMREVISION>B</ITEMREVISION>
            <CATALOGUEID/>
            <DRAWINGNUMBER>55166579/B</DRAWINGNUMBER>
            <CUSTOMERDRAWINGNUMBER/>
            <ITEMNAME>
                <NAME lang="default">Plate</NAME>
                <NAME lang="en/US">Plate</NAME>
                <NAME lang="fi/FI">Levy</NAME>
                <NAME lang="sv/SE">Pl&#229;t</NAME>
                <NAME lang="fr/FR">PLAQUE</NAME>
                <NAME lang="de/DE">Schild</NAME>
            </ITEMNAME>
            <ECNCHANGEID>ECN-BG00009133</ECNCHANGEID>
            <UNITOFMEASURE>each</UNITOFMEASURE>
            <TECHNICALDESCRIPTION>REAR FRAME NC7W</TECHNICALDESCRIPTION>
            <ADDITIONALDESCRIPTION/>
            <PRODUCTTYPEDESCRIPTION/>
            <SPAREPARTDESCRIPTION/>
            <SPAREPARTINDICATOR>Not spare part</SPAREPARTINDICATOR>
            <SPAREPARTDOCUMENTAVAILABLE>false</SPAREPARTDOCUMENTAVAILABLE>
            <RECOMMENDEDSPAREPART>false</RECOMMENDEDSPAREPART>
            <SPAREPARTSERVICECATEGORY/>
            <SPAREPARTOEM/>
            <AFTERMARKETCLASS/>
            <ITEMREVISIONPUID>oOHApQ6Gh7yqPA</ITEMREVISIONPUID>

        <ITEM>
            <ITEMNUMBER>55063477</ITEMNUMBER>
            <ITEMREVISION>@</ITEMREVISION>
            <CATALOGUEID/>
            <DRAWINGNUMBER/>
            <CUSTOMERDRAWINGNUMBER/>
            <ITEMNAME>
                <NAME lang="default">Nut, Hexagon</NAME>
                <NAME lang="en/US">Nut, Hexagon</NAME>
                <NAME lang="fi/FI">kuusiomutteri</NAME>
                <NAME lang="sv/SE">Sexkantsmutter</NAME>
                <NAME lang="de/DE">Sechskantmutter</NAME>
            </ITEMNAME>
            <ECNCHANGEID/>
            <UNITOFMEASURE>each</UNITOFMEASURE>
            <TECHNICALDESCRIPTION>M16  Weld nuts</TECHNICALDESCRIPTION>
            <ADDITIONALDESCRIPTION/>
            <PRODUCTTYPEDESCRIPTION/>
            <SPAREPARTDESCRIPTION/>
            <SPAREPARTINDICATOR>Spare part</SPAREPARTINDICATOR>
            <SPAREPARTDOCUMENTAVAILABLE>false</SPAREPARTDOCUMENTAVAILABLE>
            <RECOMMENDEDSPAREPART>false</RECOMMENDEDSPAREPART>
            <SPAREPARTSERVICECATEGORY/>
            <SPAREPARTOEM/>
            <AFTERMARKETCLASS/>
            <ITEMREVISIONPUID>g6BNAs2IQ6VoJB</ITEMREVISIONPUID>

        <ITEM>
            <ITEMNUMBER>55025930</ITEMNUMBER>
            <ITEMREVISION>@</ITEMREVISION>
            <CATALOGUEID/>
            <DRAWINGNUMBER/>
            <CUSTOMERDRAWINGNUMBER/>
            <ITEMNAME>
                <NAME lang="default">Nut, Hexagon</NAME>
                <NAME lang="en/US">Nut, Hexagon</NAME>
                <NAME lang="fi/FI">kuusiomutteri</NAME>
                <NAME lang="sv/SE">Sexkantsmutter</NAME>
                <NAME lang="de/DE">Sechskantmutter</NAME>
            </ITEMNAME>
            <ECNCHANGEID/>
            <UNITOFMEASURE>each</UNITOFMEASURE>
            <TECHNICALDESCRIPTION>M10 Weld nuts</TECHNICALDESCRIPTION>
            <ADDITIONALDESCRIPTION/>
            <PRODUCTTYPEDESCRIPTION/>
            <SPAREPARTDESCRIPTION/>
            <SPAREPARTINDICATOR>Not spare part</SPAREPARTINDICATOR>
            <SPAREPARTDOCUMENTAVAILABLE>false</SPAREPARTDOCUMENTAVAILABLE>
            <RECOMMENDEDSPAREPART>false</RECOMMENDEDSPAREPART>
            <SPAREPARTSERVICECATEGORY/>
            <SPAREPARTOEM/>
            <AFTERMARKETCLASS/>
            <ITEMREVISIONPUID>QVy0bJB_Q6VoJB</ITEMREVISIONPUID>

        </ITEM>
    </ITEMS>
    <ITEMSTRUCTURE>
        <ITEM number="55166579" version="B" parent="55166581" parentversion="B" position="1" quantity="1" unitofmeasure="each" erpcontrol="" operationsequence=""/>
        <ITEM number="55063477" version="@" parent="55166581" parentversion="B" position="2" quantity="4" unitofmeasure="each" erpcontrol="" operationsequence=""/>
        <ITEM number="55025930" version="@" parent="55166581" parentversion="B" position="3" quantity="2" unitofmeasure="each" erpcontrol="" operationsequence=""/>
    </ITEMSTRUCTURE>
</PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear: are you, for example, trying to match `55063477` from `/PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMSTRUCTURE/ITEM/@number` with, for example, `Nut, Hexagon` from `/PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMS//ITEM/NAME`? What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Following are my DB target columns that will be filled from the source xml above, these will be written from reading two different parts of the xml :  1. /PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMSTRUCTURE/ITEM/@attribute level : [number,version,parent,parentversion,position,quantity]        2. /PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMS//ITEM/ child_element level [sparepart,aftermarket manufacturer,manufacturerptnum,recospare,designown,sparepartdesc,netweight]. Please note these are all columns from the same table first  6 columns I have fill from the part 1 attribute level and next 8 from the part 2 element level mentioned earlier

Comment: taking forward your choice of the item number, I am currently able to get /PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMSTRUCTURE/ITEM/@number = 55063477 , now i would like to get its corresponding attributes from /PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMS//ITEM/ITEMNUMBER = 55063477 . I did a PoC on this earlier and I was able to get these two different element/level xml items into two different dataframes and join them together. I can implement a similar solution. But before I do that I would like to see if via usage of xpath I can access these two different levels in one go. Hope I was able to clarify.

Comment: This is used as the first debatching entry in the for each loop  : xpath(xml(string(body('Get_blob_content_using_path'))),'/PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMSTRUCTURE/ITEM')    and this is used in the insert row : xpath(xml(items('For_each')),'string(//@number)')

Comment: There's some problem with your xml sample; under `'/PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMSTRUCTURE/ITEM` you have only 3 `number`s, but under `/PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMS//ITEM/ITEMNUMBER`you have 4 text numbers. That throws off the xpath expression; see if you can fix the sample.

Comment: Its structured that way. /PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMSTRUCTURE/ITEM has 1 parent and 3 child items (1 parent common to all children hence only 3 rows). /PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMS//ITEM/ITEMNUMBER has all the 3 child and 1 parent making it 4. I some how need to reference the same item number in both the levels.

Comment: I figured that much; but the problem is that in the xml in your question, the data is NOT structured as one common parent with 3 children (as it should be) but as 4 siblings. The only hint that the first sibling is intended to be the parent is in `/PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMSTRUCTURE/ITEM` which has an attribute `parent` which in all cases refers to the first item. I don't know if the actual xml is structured correctly (i.e., one parent w/ 3 children) or the way you have it in the question. But if the latter is correct, it's going to be much more difficult do get the xpath expression right.

Comment: I get your point, yes as you say if the only the three siblings were mentioned in the /PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMS//ITEM/ element level with and in the same order then in logic app by de-batching and running a loop xpaths could ve been written to extract properly. But unfortunately this is the way they have structured the data upstream.

Comment: Could you use something like this : `//ITEM[contains(.,"55166579")]//*[contains(name(),"SPAREPART") or contains(name(),"AFTER")]|//ITEM[@number="55166579"]/@*[position()<7]` ?

Comment: Yes we have to pass parameters to match, but how do we do that without hardcoding ? More specifically how to I get like the quantity attribute of the itemnumber = 55166579 and its sparepart indicator within one go ?